# Label distinct values for Arraylist<String> with identifier

Tags: java, arraylist, distinct

I have a simple problem. I have an ArrayList (of type String) with 100'000 Names. I want to create another ArrayList (of type Integer) which also has 100'000 Elements and assignes each Element of the String ArrayList an ID-Number. Equal Names should have equal ID Numbers assigned. 
VERY BASIC EXAMPLE:
i have:   (hans, max, hans, hans, frank)
i want:   ( 1 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 3 )

I implemented a Solution which works, but is very slow (for my big dataset of 100'000 Names). I wonder someone can find a better/faster way of doing this. Thanks everyone for any tipps!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    // initialize arraylists
    ArrayList<String>  Names      = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Id         = new ArrayList<Integer>();   

    // sample data              // I want the integer Arraylist to have values:
    Names.add("Hans");          // 1 
    Names.add("Max");           // 2
    Names.add("Hans");          // 1
    Names.add("Hans");          // 1
    Names.add("Frank");         // 3

    // my solution (works, but is slow and confusing)
    int N = Names.size();
    int ID_Count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        boolean match_found = false;
        String curr_Name = Names.get(i);
        for (int check=0; check<i; check++) {
            if (curr_Name.equals(Names.get(check))) {
                Id.add(Id.get(check));
                match_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match_found==false) {
            ID_Count++;
            Id.add(ID_Count);
        }
    }

    // show result
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        System.out.println(Id.get(i) + " " + Names.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldnt suggest your approach, even though it works. have you tried HashMaps<String, Integer>, that would work better as for same key you have the requirement of having same values

Comment: Have you looked at the [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method? This might help you out when adding to your id list

Comment: no but thanks for help. Never used HashMaps, i will try. If you could post an answer with HashMaps for my sample code i would be very thankful!

Comment: Have you tried (contains method)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a faster way of doing it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // initialize arraylists
    ArrayList<String> Names      = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String,Integer> map      = new HashMap<>();

    // sample data              // I want the integer Arraylist to have values:
    Names.add("Hans");          // 1
    Names.add("Max");           // 2
    Names.add("Hans");          // 1
    Names.add("Hans");          // 1
    Names.add("Frank");         // 3

    int N = Names.size();

    int id = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        String name = Names.get(i);
        if (map.get(name) == null) {
            map.put(name,++id);
        }
    }

    // show result
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        String name = Names.get(i);
        System.out.println(map.get(name) + " " +name);
    }

}
```

Comment: great, that was exactely what i was looking for. To give you an insight what the result is on over 100'000 names: running time went down from 1min 2sec to 0.6sec! This is incredible! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm happy it could help you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you ought to use a HashMap, as it will be a lot faster/easier than working with two arrays. I would do it like this:

`Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`

This way you will be able to do `map.put("name", int id)`, and it won't allow duplicate keys (key is the "name" in your case) so you will automatically have only one key/value pair for names that are the same.